# No data while scraping whoscored website

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I try to scrap some data from whoscored website. I've been using rvest package and till now no obstacles occured.

I am interested in getting some statistics from match report (assume the website given in code below). But the suggestion about the name of element given by SelectorGadget returns nothing.

```
library(rvest)
read_html("https://www.whoscored.com/Matches/958431/MatchReport") -> web

web %>%
  html_nodes(".no-top-margin .pulsable") %>% 
  html_text() -> df
```

I also glanced the source of website but it's a bit complicated.

Does anybody have an idea how to overcome this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to scrape in particular? There's a lot going on in that webpage. There is not likely to be one command that will return the data contained in the entirety of the page in the format you desire.

Comment: Yes, I know there is a lot of data but I'm looking for some advice because I tried with different statistics and the problem was the same everytime. In my example I tried to scrap Team Match Statistics that are in the top right table of website.

Comment: I think the content is generated dynamically with a script, so you're not getting it when you pull the HTML. If you grab the page with [RSelenium](https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium) you may have better luck, though it's more work.